# onCreateOptionsMenu() is not called when starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar

When switching from activity to activity (using `startActivity(intent)`) the new activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu` method is not called.

Here is the code from activity 1 that calls the new activity to start:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_newWorkout:
            Intent intentNewWorkoutScreen = new Intent(this, NewWorkoutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentNewWorkoutScreen);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_saveWorkout:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In activity 2, here is the onCreateOptionsMenu method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    //get a reference to the adding new workout button
    MenuItem newWorkoutItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_newWorkout);
    //set it to invisible
    newWorkoutItem.setVisible(false);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

The following code is also in the onCreate() of activity 2:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//set it as the supportActionBar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Activity 2 opens and the toolbar is visible, but I cannot click any of the menu items, nor does the item I set to be invisible actually go invisible. It's worth noting that in the XML file for activity 2 and 1, I am simply using  for the toolbar layout. Activity 1's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` code works perfectly fine, as well as the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.

I there any reason why activity 2's code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreateOptionsMenu` of your 2nd `Activity`,
`return true;` instead of `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`.
By returning `true`, you say that you have already wrote the needed code to inflate the `menu`. By chaining to super class's `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, you say that let it be handled by the super class of your `Activity`.

Comment: I've already tried this. It produces the same result.

Comment: did you properly handled the `onOptionsItemSelected()` in your 2nd `Activity` ?

Comment: I copied the `onOptionsItemSelected()` from activity 1 to activity 2, with minor changes. However, I'm unable to test if that code works, because `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in activity 2 is never called. Oddly enough, the 2nd activity still displays the toolbar regardless.

Comment: are menu items visible in your 2nd activity?

Comment: yes, but that's because it <include> the layout file that includes the menu items.

Comment: what do you mean by **<include>** here ? I hope you are not talking about the tag to include one layout in another file.

Comment: And are you inflating **same menu file** in both of your `Activity` ?

Comment: um, actually I am using the <include> tag to include my toolbar layout file in the other layouts. Also, yes - I am inflating the same menu file in both of my Activities.

Comment: Can you try to replace the `<include>` tag by actual `Toolbar` tag? It might be some `id` related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a log statement to check if the method is called or not
if it is called then remove everything except this in second activity's on create options menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
return true;
}
```

if this does not work then put this in onCreate of second activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I added a Log statement, and didn't see anything show up.